# Mongoose: aggregate query for showing only most recent document version

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to create an aggregate query (or any query for that matter) that will only pull the most recent document version. I tried using the suggested aggregate query with $$ROOT but that throws an error and $$ROOT doesn't seem to be available from even the raw mongodb driver

```
        Post.collection.aggregate([
        { $sort : { uuid : 1, __v: -1}},
        { $group : { _id : "$uuid", doc: {$first: "$$ROOT"}}},
        { $match: {company: company}}
        ], callback);
```

This throws an error about a field value starting with '$' is not acceptable. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: $$ROOT is only available from MongoDB 2.6 so this seems to indicate your server is an earlier version. Also your match on "company" would not be valid since it is not a field returned by `$group`. If anything you probably really want to do that as the "first" stage in the pipeline to filter the results you are processing.

Comment: You're right, I'm using OpenShift which apparently only supports Mongo 2.4. Thanks.